# Subprocess in a loop for, program stoped

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, subprocess, popen

To sum up, I want to create a script making maps.

This script recovers the data to place on the cartography. It also opens a software to visualize the geometry in the right cutting plane, takes a photo and puts this image in the background of my graph on which I apply the recoverd data with Rectangle Matplotcollection.

My problem sets in the function opening the software :

I've realized a very simple fonction that open a geometry viewer in a certain view, take a screenshot et return the name of this screenshot.

```
def_geom_view(geom_file, command_file):
    p = Popen('\bin\bash', '-i', '-c', 'visu_geom', + 'geom_file' + '--fromfile' + 'command_file', stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate()
    return('geom_file_pic.png')
```

I'm trying to use this fonction in a for loop.

The script work for the first iteration : every thing is fine. However at the end of the first iteration, I get this (without touching anyting) :

```
[n]+ Stopped     dir-name_of_script
```

When i do 'fg' (i use it to start where i stoppend after ctrl+z) my scrit restart where it stopped and does the right thing

Do you know why ?

I've try to add the option shell=True to Popen : My script does'nt stop anymore but execute my function only in the first loop

I've try p.terminate() -> same thing than before

I've try p.kill() -> kill after the first loop

I've try signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal.SIG_IGN) -> does nothing

It looks like my child process does not return the returncode meaning its over. But i'am not sure.

How to I fix this problem ?

Thank you